# How do I set the AWS Autoscaler to use the same IP addresses?

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, autoscaling, docker-machine, rancher

I'm using rancher as a web API to my Docker Swarm. The Docker containers are running on AWS instances that we schedule to autoscale up in the morning and down at night. The new ones scale up and log on to rancher in the morning and then drop off.

Each morning when the new instances come up, they have a new IP address. Rancher holds onto the old IP address, and the old container will go into a 'zombie' state in rancher.

What would be great is if the autoscaler could try and reuse the same IP addresses each time.

**Assumptions**:

- private IPs
- VPC not EC2-classic

My question is: **How do I set the AWS Autoscaler to use the same IP addresses?**

Comment: Do you mean public IPs or private IPs?

Comment: Also, in VPC or EC2-Classic?

Comment: Don't know the anwser, but I'll give you an idea. Since you can retrieve the IPs of the machines behind the balancer, you could develop a small script that  give that info to Rancher.